# Dapper 'A parameterless default constructor or one matching signature is required'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dapper

I have a class below:

```cs
public class Employee
{
    private IEmployeeDataAccessor _employeeDataAccessor;
    public Employee(IEmployeeDataAccessor emda )
    {
        _employeeDataAccessor = emda ;
    }
    
    public int UserId { get; private set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

`IEmployeeDataAccessor` is addscoped in `startup.cs`.
In dapper I have:

```cs
return UserDb.Query<Employee>("sqlcmd for Selecting Employee here").SingleOrDefault();
```

I get the following error `'A parameterless default constructor or one matching signature is required'`
There are no issues if my constructor is parameterless, though.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Because Dapper doesn't know how to inject that dependency. And nor should it. That dependency doesn't belong there. A POCO should be as simple as possible - a bundle of properties basically.

Answer (score 1):

I think that question is answered in several comments and answer, but I will try to put everything together.

Source of problem: Dapper can't create object of your `Employee` class, because the only constructor that class has is `public Employee(IEmployeeDataAccessor emda)` and Dapper doesn't know where to get object implementing `IEmployeeDataAccessor` interface. And this is no surprise, because this is not a column of the table. Dapper is a mapper of the SQL results to the value objects. And you should not have any additional logic in such value objects.

Solution: problem comes from bad design, you should refactor `Employee` class. It should not contain any data access logic. It should be just a value class. You can do it as [@Asherguru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12734914/asherguru) suggested or you can implement it as a record class:

```
public record Employee
(
    int UserId,
    string Username
);
```

Then `return UserDb.Query<Employee>("sqlcmd for Selecting Employee here").SingleOrDefault();` should work.

And this line, as far as I understood, should go to class implementing `IEmployeeDataAccessor` i.e. this is a data access logic to get `Employee` value objects.

Answer (score -1):

Employee is model. So you can use properties only. Do not add any others.

Remove

```cs
private IEmployeeDataAccessor _employeeDataAccessor;
public Employee(IEmployeeDataAccessor emda )
{
    _employeeDataAccessor = emda ;
}
```

Use this instead:

```cs
public class Employee
{
    public int UserId { get; private set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: These are properties, not variables

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question. The asker had discovered as much.